# Flutter download a pdf file from JSON using http

Tags: flutter, http, dart

Hi everyone I want to download a pdf file from the server. I have the following response

```
I/flutter (22487): %PDF-1.3
I/flutter (22487): %ÿÿÿÿ
I/flutter (22487): 1 0 obj
I/flutter (22487): << /Creator <feff0050007200610077006e>
I/flutter (22487): /Producer <feff0050007200610077006e>
I/flutter (22487): >>
I/flutter (22487): endobj
I/flutter (22487): 2 0 obj
I/flutter (22487): << /Type /Catalog
I/flutter (22487): /Pages 3 0 R
I/flutter (22487): >>
I/flutter (22487): endobj
I/flutter (22487): 3 0 obj
I/flutter (22487): << /Type /Pages
I/flutter (22487): /Count 1
Several lines was omitted
```

And the http request I have made

```
getPDF(String jwt, int topUpId, String filename, context) async {
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'authorization': 'Bearer $jwt',
};
try {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(AppUrl + topUpId.toString() + ".pdf"),
    headers: headers,
  );

  if (response.contentLength == 0) {
    return;
  }
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path;
  File file = new File('$tempPath/$filename.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
} catch (value) {
  print(value);
}
}
```

When I make request nothings happens

Comment: how are you getting this PDF ? does the API provide the link to download the PDF ? Please post your response in a proper way so that we can understand it. I believe you are using JSON data in your response.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine here.
Just copied your code and tested it locally within MacOS Application.

If the Flutter app is running as a standalone, MacOS Application, you need to enable an entitlement to access the network.

To do this, you need to add

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Into

***$projectDir/macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements***

If this is not set, the Sandboxed App will not be able to access the Network at all.

Comment: Hi I am using MacOS too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).